# Return Hosted Agent usage via API?

Tags: azure, azure-devops

I want to create some reporting around pipelines that use MS hosted public agents to run jobs.

This info is available via the UI (Org Settings > Agent Pools > Azure Pipelines) - but not via the REST API it would seem.

I can return all Agent Pools:

GET [https://dev.azure.com/{organization}/_apis/distributedtask/pools?api-version=7.1-preview.1](https://dev.azure.com/%7Borganization%7D/_apis/distributedtask/pools?api-version=7.1-preview.1)

...and then filter on the "isHosted" property - but the pool info has no run history.

Alternatively I can loop through all projects in the Org (lots!), loop through all pipelines, then finally loop through all runs for each pipeline - but the run doesn't have an agent property either.

I tried looking at Service Hooks to trigger a webhook when a build is run to see if I could pull the agent / pool detail from the payload - buts its not in there either.

Any other ideas welcome.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When encountered those situation, you always have two ways.

**1, First of all, if UI can show what you want, you can handle the data via python crawler.**

```
#python crawler get the content of the page

import requests

url = "https://dev.azure.com/<Organization Name>/_settings/agentpools?poolId=9&view=jobs"

payload={}
headers = {
  'Authorization': 'Basic <Personal Access Token>',
}

response = requests.request("GET", url, headers=headers, data=payload)

print(response.text)

#save the content to a file
with open('jobs.html', 'w', encoding='utf-8') as f:
    f.write(response.text)
```

After saving the data, use the regular expression to filter the data you want.

(This method is just a suggestion for common handling.)

**2, Or you can use this REST API to query the public agents run history of your current situation:**

`https://dev.azure.com/<Organization Name>/_apis/distributedtask/pools/<Pool ID>/jobrequests`

Public or private can be distinguished by ***ParallelismTag***:

[image]

Comment: Thank you.  I can't find that jobrequests API in the docs anywhere!   Using that I can lookup the definition - which generally equates to the pipeline name.